# Pushing master to heroku Play! Framework 2.0 App

Tags: git, heroku, playframework

I have committed my code to git successfully, and successfully logged into heroku and started an app, but when I try to do `git push heroku master` i get:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Is there some step I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku doesn't know who you are based on you SSH keys, you should be able to fix it with `heroku keys:add` - read more at http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys.